# how to remove listener from cell editing plugin in ExtJs?

Tags: extjs

can anybody please help me out here ?

I want to remove the beforeedit listener at runtime from cell editing plugin.

I added the listener on plugin using following code.

```
var gridPlugin = Ext.getCmp(gridId).getPlugin(pluginId);
gridPlugin.addListener(eventName,function(editor,e,eOpts){callbackFunction(editor, e, eOpts);});
```

but now i am not able to remove the listener.

I am trying with following code.

```
var gridPlugin = Ext.getCmp(gridId).getPlugin(pluginId);
gridPlugin.removeListener(eventName);
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

`Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing.removeListener`'s signature is: `( eventName, fn, [scope] )` [(see documentation)](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing-method-removeListener) which means, that apart from supplying the event name for which the listener should be detached, you need to provide the listener function as well. The code that should work would be:

```
var gridPlugin = Ext.getCmp(gridId).getPlugin(pluginId),
    listnerFunction = function(editor,e,eOpts){callbackFunction(editor, e, eOpts);}

gridPlugin.addListener(eventName,listnerFunction);
```

then

```
var gridPlugin = Ext.getCmp(gridId).getPlugin(pluginId);
gridPlugin.removeListener(eventName, listenerFunction);
```

Note that you need to have a reference to `listenerFunction` available when detaching it.

Comment: i tried it but it is not working. i passed the same function as a second argument to removeListener method.

Comment: Note, that you must pass the reference to the original listener function, not anonymous function with same code.

Comment: how do i do that ? i tried passing only function(editor,e,eOpts){} but it is not working. can you please post some example.

Comment: The example has been in the answer right from the start. Notice how I first assign the function to `listenerFunction` handle, then I use this handle to both register and unregister the listener.